# Androidアプリ開発で、afreechartのshapeが表示されない。

Tags: android

JAVAでAndroidのアプリを開発しています。
afreechartを使用して時系列グラフを描いているのですが、データがある箇所に点(shape)が出せずに困っています。
ソースコードは下記です。これで出ると思っているのですが…。

```
public class SampleChart {

public void createChart(View view) {

    TimeSeriesCollection data = new TimeSeriesCollection();

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("時系列データ");
    series.add(new Month(7, 2007), 120);
    series.add(new Month(8, 2007), 140);
    series.add(new Month(9, 2007), 150);
    series.add(new Month(10, 2007), 190);
    series.add(new Month(11, 2007), 230);
    series.add(new Month(12, 2007), 280);

    data.addSeries(series);

    AFreeChart chart =
            ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                    "PV推移", // グラフタイトル
                    null, // X軸ラベル
                    "PV", // Y軸ラベル
                    data,
                    false, // ← 凡例無し
                    false,
                    false);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

    XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
    if (r instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) r;
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, 5.0f); // 太さ
        renderer.setSeriesPaintType(0, new SolidColor(Color.rgb(255, 166, 0))); // 色
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, new RoundRectShape(-6, -6, 12, 12, 6, 6));
        renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);
        renderer.setSeriesShapesFilled(0, true);
        renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
        renderer.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
    }

    GraphView graphView = (GraphView) view;
    graphView.setChart(chart);

}

}
```

何が足りないのでしょうか？

実行すると下記のようなグラフになり、黄色の線のデータの箇所に点(shape)が出ません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();`がないので、`plot`が未定義でビルドが通らないと思いますが、実際のコードではそこは解決されているのでしょうか？コード自体はあっていて、shapeの表示がされますね。端末依存でこの手の問題が起きたような記憶がちょっとありますがうる覚えです。

Comment: quesera2さん、コメントありがとうございます。実際のコードには
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
というコードが入っています。それでも、shapeが表示されません。
やはり、端末依存の問題なのでしょうか？
近々、新しい携帯を買うので、そちらでも試してみます。

Comment: XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
を
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
に変えてみましたが、それでも、shapeが表示されませんでした。
ご報告まで。